# Algebraically flavoured functional analysis book

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on functional analysis that would suit someone who is more **algebraically/geometrically oriented** and seeks to learn the subject with the goal of **using it later for geometric analysis** and/or **topological k-theory** (and maybe noncommutative geometry in the far future).

What would be a good book fitting this description?

I have the relevant background in basic measure theory, complex analysis and linear algebra.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that

> A. Ya. Helemskii, *[Lectures and Exercises on Functional Analysis](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=mmono-233)*, Translations of Mathematical Monographs , vol. 233 (2006).

in conjunction with some standard book such as

> G. K. Pedersen, *Analysis Now*, Springer-Verlag, (1989).

should suit you well. Note that Pedersen's book itself contains lots of basic information about Banach and operator algebras which is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think to prepare Geometrical Analysis the book of Abraham, Marsden and Ratiu Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications is quite useful. 
And maybe Dieudonné is a good author to look at. He is from the so called Bourbaki group which tried to formulate known results in a most abstract way. It is called Éléments d’Analyse or similar.